# What is the (best) short name for a Silverlight Application?

Tags: silverlight

I've been wondering what the right shorthand name to call my Silverlight Applications is - it seems a bit cumbersome to use the full name, and not so communicative in relation to customers.

Here are some (tongue in cheek) suggestions - I'm working on a:

1) Silverlet
2) SLApp
3) Trinket
4) Xap
5) SLash
6) SLugin

Anyone knows the official short name or have other suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

appSLet, SLapplet, SLApper

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago Silverlight name was WPFE or WPF/E (WPF everywhere).
Really short and meaningful name.